How do I set an alarm for every other week?
I have an Asus Zenfone 8 and want to set an alarm that goes off every other week on Fridays. The default Google alarm lets me set a weekly alarm, but I don't see an option for every other week.
How do I set an alarm to go off every other week?

Since this question is also tagged with [calendar]: How do I create a calendar event that repeats every other week?

Maybe with an app such as Tasker or Macrodroid, and you can set up the automation yourself

I use "Digical" for that purpose.
That has so much more options, including agenda alarms for repetitions every other week, month, etc. and any number of days. I can recommend it to everybody.
I have it for many years now (and as many Android versions). Currently I am running it on Android 13 on a Sony Xperia 10 III.

If you are using a Samsung mobile, then you can use the Clock app to set the alarm for the other week. You can follow these instructions. Turn off the weekly alarm. You will see "Turn back on for the other week". Click on it and it will show alarm sound on the other week.

While this may be a solution, I think it's still troublesome for the user required to turn off and on the alarm manually every week.
